# Bootstrap DateTime picker only month and day

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Display month and date only in bootstrap datetimepicker not working in IE.

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MMMM',
    pickTime: false,
});
```

Datetimepicker for Bootstrap v3. version: 3.1.3. And I tried with IE 9 and 11.

Same code working in chrome. Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: its always helpfull to add a link to which library you use, there are thousands of bootstrap datetimepickers, also its worth to mention which ie version used

Comment: Datetimepicker for Bootstrap v3. version : 3.1.3.. IE -9

Comment: really, a link to the library would be awesome helpful

Comment: https://github.com/atais/angular-eonasdan-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

The format seems to be wrong, there is no `MMMM`

try `DD-MM` to get `Monday-January`